# How can I get results for global locations, but also suggest local locations within the same search?

Tags: ios, swift, search, foursquare

Im setting up a search bar, and would like the user to see a list of local locations, and then if not satisified by the initial list be able to perform an additional search with a global parameter. Often times the locaiton will not be local.

We are able to split this into two searches via a filter, the user has to first select if theyre doing a local or global search. We want to avoid this

I expect a user in NYC to open the search tool and see a list of local locations, but then have the ability to search for other locations globally.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read this guide on how to ask a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Please specify local means which storage you are using. In your problem is to make a algorithm which first search in local and if not found go with global search.

For this you need to be so carefull take local search accurately and make your processes in background while searching in local.

If you need more assistance please share full description and code if possible.

Thanks